# How can I have the user input only 5 integers/strings a into a list?

Tags: python, list, input

My class is starting to add lists into our code. I understand how to have the user input information and loop it forever until the user types 'n' (or something like that) thus exiting the program.

My part of my current assignment is to have the user input 5 exam scores, store the scores into a list, and then display the list.

How do I have the user input type in ONLY 5 exam scores and store it into a list?

Thank you fellow programmers for helping a new student to the coding world.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, sharing your code is encouraged. Also, while many of us are happy to help, please note that this is not a homework-assignment-forum. If you have *specific* questions that have not been answered elsewhere, they are always welcome.

Comment: It's not your question, son, that angers me so. It's your lack of an attempt to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation on `for` loops in Python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score -1):

import sys

def main():
    print sys.argv

if__name__ == '**main**':
  main()

Add the command line argument that you want to the list

## python hello.py aaa bbb ccc replace aaa bbb ccc with your stuff